# List of tricks for finding residues

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, singularity

Are there some tricks to finding residues to various complex functions? I realize that the residue of a complex function is the coefficient $a_{-1}$ of the Laurent expansion of said function.

Are there any cool tricks, say when you are dealing with a function that has singularities, or a function that has a specific format? For example, I came across a theorem that if f has a simple pole at $z_0$ and g is holomorphic at $z_0$, then $Res_{z_0}(fg) = g(z_0)Res_{z_0}(f)$.

Does anyone know of a site or reference sheet that has a list of cool ways to find the residue, please let me know! Or if there are some good ones that you can list. I am trying to find a simple list, but have not come across any.

Comment: List of tricks: 1. Cauchy's Integral Formula, 2. Look at 1, etc.

Comment: I meant something more along the lines of, if you expand the function and it has the form $\frac{i}{2(z+i)} + \frac{i}{2(z-i)}$, then the residue at i is $2\pi i \frac{i}{2} =  -\pi$, because that is the coefficient for the term at $(z-i)^{-1}$